# Use two django model manager at the same time

Tags: django, django-models, django-managers

If I have the following two models:

```
class A(model.Models):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 10)

class B(model.Models):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    type = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
```

I want to get such A objects:

1. its name is 'testa'
2. At least one of the B objects related to it has name 'testb'
   and type 'typeb'

Now that the query involves two managers, i.e. A.objects and A.b_set, I wonder how to make the query at one time.

I don't want a intersection of two querysets because one of them maybe large enough to cause performance problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
a_queryset = A.objects.filter(name='testa', b__name='testb').distinct()
```

Basically, lowercase of the model name

[Documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

[`distinct()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) eliminates any duplicate `A` objects

Comment: Wow, never notice this works. Then why do they invent a b_set Manager? The objects manager is enough.

Comment: This is for queryset and the_set is for single object.  Both are useful

Comment: I edited my question and could you please help me again? The new question's key point is the same object b must fulfill two conditions

Comment: i dont understand what you need

Comment: if you create a new question with your existing code, you have a better chance of getting a good answer.